Insert an xml inside another one
I am trying to use an invoice certifier, but the way in which I have to send the invoices is a bit special, since there must be an xml with the certifier data and inside this xml, there must be the xml of the invoice.
from odoo.exceptions import UserError # type: ignore

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

from . import factura as FACT

def certificar_documento(xml_certificar):
    url = "https://url/certifier/example"
    # xml_enviar = ET.tostring(xml_certificar.getroot(), encoding="UTF-8", method="xml")
    xml_certificar.write("D:\\Documentos\\desarrollos\\fel\\prueba.xml", encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)

    # respuesta = requests.post(url, data=xml_enviar)
    # raise UserError(respuesta.text)


def xml_envio(xml_generado):
    xml_generado_str = ET.tostring(xml_generado.getroot(), encoding="UTF-8", method="xml").decode("UTF-8")
    root = ET.Element(
        "SOAP-ENV:Envelope",
        {
            "xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enveloe/",
            "xmlns:ws": "http://www.fact.com.mx/schema/ws"
        }
    )

    soap_header = ET.SubElement(root, "SOAP-ENV:Header")
    soap_body = ET.SubElement(root, "SOAP-ENV:Body")
    request_transaction = ET.SubElement(soap_body, "ws:RequestTransaction")
    requestor = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Requestor").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    transaction = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Transaction").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    country = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Country").text = "GT"
    entity = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Entity").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    user = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:User").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    user_name = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:UserName").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    data_uno = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Data1").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"
    data_dos = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Data2").text = xml_generado_str
    data_tres = ET.SubElement(request_transaction, "ws:Data3").text = "EXAMPLE_VALUE"

    certificacion = ET.ElementTree(root)
    return certificacion

def facturacion_electronica(self, factura):
    if not factura.invoice_date:
        factura.invoice_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/Guatemala")).date()
        if factura.invoice_date != factura.invoice_date_due:
            factura.tipo_factura = "fact_cambiaria"
        elif factura.invoice_date == factura.invoice_date_due:
            factura.tipo_factura = "fact"


    tree = FACT.generar_factura(self, factura)
    xml_certificar = xml_envio(tree)
    certificar_documento(xml_certificar)

The certifier is used in this way, however, when the xml is generated, it is generated in this way.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/enveloe/"
  xmlns:ws="http://www.fact.com.mx/schema/ws">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ws:RequestTransaction>
      <ws:Requestor>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:Requestor>
      <ws:Transaction>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:Transaction>
      <ws:Country>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:Country>
      <ws:Entity>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:Entity>
      <ws:User>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:User>
      <ws:UserName>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:UserName>
      <ws:Data1>EXAMPLE_VALUE</ws:Data1>
      <ws:Data2>
        &lt;dte:GTDocumento xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:dte="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.2.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="0.1"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.gt/dte/fel/0.2.0"&gt;&lt;dte:SAT
        ClaseDocumento="dte"&gt;&lt;dte:DTE ID="DatosCertificados"&gt;&lt;dte:DatosEmision
        ID="DatosEmision"&gt;&lt;dte:DatosGenerales CodigoMoneda="GTQ"
        FechaHoraEmision="2024-09-20T00:00:00-06:00" Tipo="FACT" /&gt;&lt;dte:Emisor
        AfiliacionIVA="GEN" CodigoEstablecimiento="1" CorreoEmisor="info@proelca.com"
        NITEmisor="11201094K" NombreComercial="PROEL_DEMO" NombreEmisor="PRODUCTOS ELECTRICOS
        CENTROAMERICANOS, S.A"&gt;&lt;dte:DireccionEmisor&gt;&lt;dte:Direccion&gt;Calzada Aguilar
        Batres 42-21 Zona 12, Guatemala,
        Guatemala&lt;/dte:Direccion&gt;&lt;dte:CodigoPostal&gt;01012&lt;/dte:CodigoPostal&gt;&lt;dte:Municipio
        /&gt;&lt;dte:Departamento&gt;False&lt;/dte:Departamento&gt;&lt;dte:Pais&gt;GT&lt;/dte:Pais&gt;&lt;/dte:DireccionEmisor&gt;&lt;/dte:Emisor&gt;&lt;dte:Receptor
        CorreoReceptor="" NombreReceptor="MARTÍNEZ,RUIZ,,DANIEL,ALEJANDRO"
        IDReceptor="111524970"&gt;&lt;dte:DireccionReceptor&gt;&lt;dte:Direccion&gt;Kilómetro 22.5
        Carretera Ciudad Quetzale, Jardines de San
        Gabriel&lt;/dte:Direccion&gt;&lt;dte:CodigoPostal&gt;00000&lt;/dte:CodigoPostal&gt;&lt;dte:Municipio&gt;Guatemala&lt;/dte:Municipio&gt;&lt;dte:Departamento&gt;Ciudad
        Quetzal&lt;/dte:Departamento&gt;&lt;dte:Pais&gt;GT&lt;/dte:Pais&gt;&lt;/dte:DireccionReceptor&gt;&lt;/dte:Receptor&gt;&lt;dte:Frases&gt;&lt;dte:Frase
        TipoFrase="1" CodigoEscenario="1" /&gt;&lt;dte:Frase TipoFrase="2" CodigoEscenario="1"
        /&gt;&lt;/dte:Frases&gt;&lt;dte:Items&gt;&lt;dte:Item BienOServicio="B"
        NumeroLinea="1"&gt;&lt;dte:Cantidad&gt;780.0&lt;/dte:Cantidad&gt;&lt;dte:UnidadMedida&gt;UND&lt;/dte:UnidadMedida&gt;&lt;dte:Descripcion&gt;[
        ] Producto
        uno&lt;/dte:Descripcion&gt;&lt;dte:PrecioUnitario&gt;50.0&lt;/dte:PrecioUnitario&gt;&lt;dte:Precio&gt;39000.0&lt;/dte:Precio&gt;&lt;dte:Descuento&gt;0.0&lt;/dte:Descuento&gt;&lt;dte:Impuestos&gt;&lt;dte:Impuesto&gt;&lt;dte:NombreCorto&gt;IVA&lt;/dte:NombreCorto&gt;&lt;dte:CodigoUnidadGravable&gt;1&lt;/dte:CodigoUnidadGravable&gt;&lt;dte:MontoGravable&gt;34821.43&lt;/dte:MontoGravable&gt;&lt;dte:MontoImpuesto&gt;4178.57&lt;/dte:MontoImpuesto&gt;&lt;/dte:Impuesto&gt;&lt;/dte:Impuestos&gt;&lt;dte:Total&gt;39000.0&lt;/dte:Total&gt;&lt;/dte:Item&gt;&lt;/dte:Items&gt;&lt;dte:Totales&gt;&lt;dte:TotalImpuestos&gt;&lt;dte:TotalImpuesto
        NombreCorto="IVA" TotalMontoImpuesto="4178.57"
        /&gt;&lt;/dte:TotalImpuestos&gt;&lt;dte:GranTotal&gt;39000.0&lt;/dte:GranTotal&gt;&lt;/dte:Totales&gt;&lt;/dte:DatosEmision&gt;&lt;/dte:DTE&gt;&lt;dte:Adenda&gt;&lt;envios-orden-compra
        /&gt;&lt;numerointerno&gt;/&lt;/numerointerno&gt;&lt;telefonocliente
        /&gt;&lt;inicialesvendedor&gt;Administrator&lt;/inicialesvendedor&gt;&lt;codigocliente&gt;7&lt;/codigocliente&gt;&lt;contado&gt;X&lt;/contado&gt;&lt;dias&gt;0&lt;/dias&gt;&lt;/dte:Adenda&gt;&lt;/dte:SAT&gt;&lt;/dte:GTDocumento&gt;</ws:Data2>
      <ws:Data3>1</ws:Data3>
    </ws:RequestTransaction>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

What should I do so that the invoice xml is inserted with the correct format?
